# Uber Uploader XML ERROR: XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED at line 1 with hwdMediaShare

Tags: php, xml, joomla

Uber uploader was working perfectly, and then suddenly it doesn't work and has this error:

> XML ERROR: XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED at line 1

It occasionally starts working again and then goes back to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because the joomla 32-bit random form token occasionally begins with a number, causing an invalid tag in the .redirect xml file.

A quick fix is to rename the invalid xml tags before parsing:

> 1. Open joomla\components\com_hwdmediashare\libraries\uber\ubr_finished_lib.php
> 2. Add the following code to `function parseFeed()`
>
>    ```
>    # Precede invalid tag names with key_
>    $xml_post_data = preg_replace('/\<([0-9][^\>]*)\>([^\<]*)\<\/([0-9][^\>]*)\>/',
>    '<key_$1>$2</key_$3>', $xml_post_data);
>    ```

Or if you don't need the joomla form token then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was an invalid character inside a tag.
To validate my XML, I used:  https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

These chars has to be replaced inside tags afaik.

```
$x   = str_replace(
                ['&'    , '<'   , '>'   , '"'     , "'"     ], 
                ['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&apos;'], $x);
```